# Strange bug in NSMutableArray removeObject

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, ios, nsmutablearray

I have this snippet:

```
1: if ((s >= kEnumValue1) && (s <= kEnumValue2)) {
2:   MyObject * o = [self findObjectFor:s];
3:   if ([o isValidFor:self]) {
4:     [arrayOfMyObjects removeObject:o];
5:     for (MyObject * mo in arrayOfMyObjects) {
6:       ...
7:     }
8:   }
9: }
```

For some really weird reason, when my code reaches line 4, if I step over, it goes back to the start of the method on the same thread, without going thru lines 5-. Does anybody have any clue why this happens?

removeObject on NSMutableArray does not mention any exception.

Comment: Are you debugging in debug configuration? Optimizations can make the flow of your code jumpy.

Comment: yes. I'm debugging with debug profile. The code is really called twice, because I raise an error when I try to find "s" and it does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, after lots of debugging in all classes on my project, I found that, when MyObject's release is called, it calls "release" on another class (since it is the last reference, it calls "dealloc"), once again for a third class, and then, it invokes removeObjectForKey:nil in NSMutableDictionary. This raises an NSInvalidArgumentException that is not logged at all. Way too evil...

Comment: Gotta love those.  Think of how much you've grown as an iOS programmer by tracking that down. ;)

Comment: Exact. I miss the time when understanding UITableView was my biggest problem. :D

Answer (score 2):

It is safe to assume that you did *not* find a bug in `removeObject:` (unless you wrote your own).

Have you checked `arrayOfMyObjects`?  Is it non-nil? Does it contain anything?

Comment: Yes, it was non-nil, contained only the removed instance